# ZF2 Extract headers from response

Tags: class, curl, header, zend-framework2, protected

I make use of cURL with zend framework, it gives me back the headers and site content.

I use this output in another class where I want to extract the headers from the curl output to see if a language is ser (content-language).

The output has protected classes such as response and headers, I tried to set the class headers and response to try getting the header values by this but it gives me no results.

(curl output => $this->content)

> ```
> class Zend\Http\Response#258 (7) { protected $recommendedReasonPhrases => array(57) { [100] => string(8) "Continue"
> ```
>
> [101] => string(19) "Switching Protocols" [102] => string(10)
>   "Processing" [200] => string(2) "OK" [201] => string(7) "Created"
>   [202] => string(8) "Accepted" [203] => string(29) "Non-Authoritative
>   Information" [204] => string(10) "No Content" [205] => string(13)
>   "Reset Content" [206] => string(15) "Partial Content" [207] =>
>   string(12) "Multi-status" [208] => string(16) "Already Reported" [300]
>   => string(16) "Multiple Choices" [301] => string(17) "Moved Permanently" [302] => string(5) "Found" [303] => string(9) "See Other"
>   [304] => string(12) "Not Modified" [305] => string(9) "Use Proxy"
>   [306] => string(12) "Switch Proxy" [307] => string(18) "Temporary
>   Redirect" [400] => string(11) "Bad Request" [401] => string(12)
>   "Unauthorized" [402] => string(16) "Payment Required" [403] =>
>   string(9) "Forbidden" [404] => string(9) "Not Found" [405] =>
>   string(18) "Method Not Allowed" [406] => string(14) "Not Acceptable"
>   [407] => string(29) "Proxy Authentication Required" [408] =>
>   string(16) "Request Time-out" [409] => string(8) "Conflict" [410] =>
>   string(4) "Gone" [411] => string(15) "Length Required" [412] =>
>   string(19) "Precondition Failed" [413] => string(24) "Request Entity
>   Too Large" [414] => string(21) "Request-URI Too Large" [415] =>
>   string(22) "Unsupported Media Type" [416] => string(31) "Requested
>   range not satisfiable" [417] => string(18) "Expectation Failed" [418]
>   => string(12) "I'm a teapot" [422] => string(20) "Unprocessable Entity" [423] => string(6) "Locked" [424] => string(17) "Failed
>   Dependency" [425] => string(20) "Unordered Collection" [426] =>
>   string(16) "Upgrade Required" [428] => string(21) "Precondition
>   Required" [429] => string(17) "Too Many Requests" [431] => string(31)
>   "Request Header Fields Too Large" [500] => string(21) "Internal Server
>   Error" [501] => string(15) "Not Implemented" [502] => string(11) "Bad
>   Gateway" [503] => string(19) "Service Unavailable" [504] => string(16)
>   "Gateway Time-out" [505] => string(26) "HTTP Version not supported"
>   [506] => string(23) "Variant Also Negotiates" [507] => string(20)
>   "Insufficient Storage" [508] => string(13) "Loop Detected" [511] =>
>   string(31) "Network Authentication Required" } protected $statusCode
>   => int(200) protected $reasonPhrase => string(2) "OK" protected $version => string(3) "1.1" protected $headers => class
>   Zend\Http\Headers#257 (3) { protected $pluginClassLoader => NULL
>   protected $headersKeys => array(15) { [0] => string(4) "date" [1] =>
>   string(6) "server" [2] => string(10) "xpoweredby" [3] => string(12)
>   "xdrupalcache" [4] => string(7) "expires" [5] => string(12)
>   "lastmodified" [6] => string(12) "cachecontrol" [7] => string(4)
>   "etag" [8] => string(15) "contentlanguage" [9] => string(10)
>   "xgenerator" [10] => string(4) "vary" [11] => string(15)
>   "contentencoding" [12] => string(13) "contentlength" [13] =>
>   string(10) "connection" [14] => string(11) "contenttype" } protected
>   $headers => array(15) { [0] => array(2) { 'name' => string(4) "Date"
>   'line' => string(35) "Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 09:57:42 GMT" } [1] =>
>   array(2) { 'name' => string(6) "Server" 'line' => string(30) "Server:
>   Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)" } [2] => array(2) { 'name' => string(12)
>   "X-Powered-By" 'line' => string(35) "X-Powered-By:
>   PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18" } [3] => array(2) { 'name' => string(14)
>   "X-Drupal-Cache" 'line' => string(20) "X-Drupal-Cache: MISS" } [4] =>
>   array(2) { 'name' => string(7) "Expires" 'line' => string(38)
>   "Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT" } [5] => array(2) { 'name' =>
>   string(13) "Last-Modified" 'line' => string(46) "Last-Modified: Tue,
>   26 Feb 2013 09:57:42 +0000" } [6] => array(2) { 'name' => string(13)
>   "Cache-Control" 'line' => string(32) "Cache-Control: public,
>   max-age=0" } [7] => array(2) { 'name' => string(4) "ETag" 'line' =>
>   string(20) "ETag: "1361872662-1"" } [8] => array(2) { 'name' =>
>   string(16) "Content-Language" 'line' => string(20) "Content-Language:
>   ru" } [9] => array(2) { 'name' => string(11) "X-Generator" 'line' =>
>   string(41) "X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" } [10] =>
>   array(2) { 'name' => string(4) "Vary" 'line' => string(28) "Vary:
>   Cookie,Accept-Encoding" } [11] => array(2) { 'name' => string(16)
>   "Content-Encoding" 'line' => string(22) "Content-Encoding: gzip" }
>   [12] => array(2) { 'name' => string(14) "Content-Length" 'line' =>
>   string(20) "Content-Length: 7139" } [13] => array(2) { 'name' =>
>   string(10) "Connection" 'line' => string(17) "Connection: close" }
>   [14] => array(2) { 'name' => string(12) "Content-Type" 'line' =>
>   string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" } } } protected
>   $metadata => array(0) { } protected $content => string(23711)

(code)

```
   $response = new Response();
    $response->getHeaders($this->content);
    $headers = new Headers();
    var_dump($headers->get('Content-Language'));
```

(generates)

```
bool(false)
```

(var_dump of $response->getHeaders)

> class Zend\Http\Headers#259 (3) { protected $pluginClassLoader => NULL
>   protected $headersKeys => array(0) { } protected $headers => array(0)
>   { } }

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: Can you add your current (not working) code?

Comment: just update my post :)

Comment: Why are you doing `$headers = new Headers();` ?

Comment: I tried this one because of it's function description 'Get all headers of a certain name/type' I need to extract the 'Content-Language' header from $this->content

Comment: then it's `var_dump($this->content->getHeaders()->get('Content-Language');`. Seems like you are assuming too much magic ;) Constructors in ZF2 tend to do nothing by design, and usually don't read environment variables.

Comment: Humm, that works better yes :), if you set your comment as answer I will accept :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not build a new `Zend\Http\Response` nor a new `Zend\Http\Headers`, but just use the ones that are already in `$this->content` in your current context:

```
var_dump($this->content->getHeaders()->get('Content-Language'));
```